# Conditional probability, two vector valued RVs on a circle.

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, conditional-probability, geometric-probability

Given two vector valued RVs $ X,Y \in S_1$ (the unit circle) that are uniformly distributed. We choose a fixed vector $a \in S_1$, e.g. in x-direction: $a=e_x$.

We then sample once from both distributions and obtain $x_1, y_1 \in S_1$ in the first run. The resulting vectors $z$ are then chosen as follows:
$$z_1=x_1 \text{ if } |a \cdot x_1| \ge |a \cdot y_1| \text{ and } z_1=y_1 \text{ if } |a \cdot x_1| < |a \cdot y_1|$$

What is the resulting density $\rho(z|a)$ of the vectors $z$? What integrals do I have to evaluate and why?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: The angles $\angle UOX, \angle UOY$ ($O = (0, 0)$, $U = O + a$) will also have a uniform distribution on $[-\pi, \pi]$, and the problem statement would choose the angle that has a lower absolute value.

Comment: That is correct. How do I formally derive the correct resulting density? And how do I include the condition?

Comment: Are $X, Y, a$ independent, and what's the distribution of $a$? For the conditional probability, you'll need to calculate the joint density $f_{Z,A}(z,a)$ and divide it by the marginal density $f_A(a)$. Obviously $f_{Z,A}(z e^{it},a e^{it}) = f_{Z,A} (z,a)$, so you only really need $f_{Z,A}(z, 0)$.

Comment: For the density on angles with $a = (1,0)$, you can use [this](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Probability/Transformation_of_Probability_Densities#Mapping_of_a_Random_Vector_to_a_Random_Variable_(n%3E1,_m=1)) formula with $(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2$: $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial z} \int \limits_{\{(x,y) | f(x,y) \le z\}} \rho_x(x) \rho_y(y) dx dy$. Then remap the result to the circle with necessary transformations. The problem is in the limits of the integration...

Comment: X, Y are independent. The distribution of a does not matter (It can be an arbitrary unit vector , but it is fixed). But why is the Tupel $(x, y)$ from $R^2$? $x, y$ are vectors.

Comment: You're 100% right, I meant the corresponding angles (same with $z$). The integration will be over a subset of $[-\pi,pi]^2$ that would depend on the angle of $z$.